# RecyclerView Overwrite last element a couple times

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using MVVC pattern and I'm populating a **recyclerView** with data from database using **Room**. At the *Logcat*, data return correctly and is looped correctly, but **recyclerview** display seven elements and in the eighth starts to overwrite it with the nineth and tenth elements e after that create 2 more elements with the first 2 elements from list.

I'm coudn't find what is wrong with my code.

So, I'm asking for some help.

AvaliacaoFragment.kt:

```
class AvaliacaoFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var ctx: Context
    private var _binding: FragmentAvaliacaoBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var textoSemSecoes: TextView
    private lateinit var nomeAvaliacao: TextView
    private lateinit var dataAvaliacao: TextView
    private val args by navArgs<AvaliacaoFragmentArgs>()


    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentAvaliacaoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avaliacoes, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ctx = view.context

        // dialogNovaAvaliacao = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(ctx, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen)
        // dialogNovaAvaliacao = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(ctx,R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
        // val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()

        textoSemSecoes = view.findViewById(R.id.texto_sem_secoes)
        nomeAvaliacao = view.findViewById(R.id.nome_avaliacao)
        dataAvaliacao = view.findViewById(R.id.data_avaliacao)

        nomeAvaliacao.text = args.currentAvaliacao.nome
        dataAvaliacao.text = args.currentAvaliacao.dataCriacao

        /*
        btnAddAvaliacao = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_avaliacao)
        btnAddAvaliacao.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_avaliacoes_to_addAvaliacaoFragment)
        }
        */

        // Recycler
        val recyclerAdapter = SecaoAdapter()
        val recyclerView = binding.secaoRecyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // ViewModelFactory para passar argumentos para a ViewModel
        val factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return SecaoViewModel(Application(), args.currentAvaliacao.id) as T
            }
        }

        // ViewModel
        mSecaoViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(SecaoViewModel::class.java)
        mSecaoViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { secaoList ->
            if(secaoList.isNotEmpty()){
                Log.d(TAG, "secaoList: ${secaoList.toString()}")
                Log.d(TAG, "secaoList.size: ${secaoList.size}")
                textoSemSecoes.visibility = View.GONE
                recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                recyclerAdapter.setData(secaoList.sortedBy { it.codigo.toInt() })
            } else {
                textoSemSecoes.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG: String = AvaliacaoFragment::class.java.name

        lateinit var mSecaoViewModel: SecaoViewModel
        private lateinit var btnAddSecao: FloatingActionButton
        private lateinit var dialogNovaSecao: MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

    }
}
```

SecaoAdapter.kt:

```
class SecaoAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<SecaoAdapter.SecaoViewHolder>() {

    private val TAG: String = SecaoAdapter::class.java.name
    private var secaoList = emptyList<Secao>()
    private lateinit var binding: ItemSecaoBinding

    class SecaoViewHolder(itemBinding: ItemSecaoBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SecaoViewHolder {
        binding = ItemSecaoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return SecaoViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return secaoList.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SecaoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "position: $position")
        val currentItem = secaoList[position]
        Log.d(TAG, "currentItem: ${currentItem.toString()}")

        binding.secaoCodigo.text = currentItem.codigo
        binding.secaoNome.text = currentItem.nome
        binding.secaoMediaTotal.text = currentItem.mediaPositivo.toString()
        binding.secaoPerguntasNaoAplicaveis.text = currentItem.qdePerguntasNaoAplicaveis.toString()
        binding.secaoPerguntasRespondidas.text = currentItem.qdePerguntasRespondidas.toString()
        binding.secaoPerguntasTotais.text = currentItem.qdePerguntas.toString()

        binding.cardSecao.setOnClickListener {
            val action = AvaliacaoFragmentDirections.actionAvaliacaoFragmentToSecaoFragment(currentItem)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    fun setData(secao: List<Secao>){
        this.secaoList = secao
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

fragment_avaliacao.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context=".ui.secoes.AvaliacaoFragment">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_titulo_avaliacao"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nome_avaliacao"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/padrao_avaliacao_sem_nome"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorIcons"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_avaliacao"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/padrao_formato_data_hora"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_sem_secoes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container_titulo_avaliacao"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/nenhuma_secao_criada"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/secaoRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container_titulo_avaliacao"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat loop from secaoList at the SecaoAdapter (is looping correctly to all elements):
[image]

I create a gif to show what is happening with the elements on recyclerView:

[image]

Here you can see that it displays seventh element then eighth is replaced by nineth and subsequently replaced by tenth. And final two elements (*that should be ninth and tenth*) is constructed with first and second list elements.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: When data fetched from DB, are they sorted? or you sort them after getting them?

Comment: because in SecaoAdapter in setData method, all the list that fetched from DB are replaced with previous list and then dataSetChanged() called.There should be guarantee that both list(list in adapter and new fetched list) have same item in certain positions.

Comment: @com_run, that wouldn't cause this. `notifyDataSetChanged()` means to completely refresh and assume nothing, even the size, is the same.

Comment: This is a stumper. I can't find any errors in your code. Can you also log something in your `setData` function to see if it is getting called while you scroll? It is very odd that the values are changing when the view is already on screen and you aren't doing anything with stable IDs.

Comment: it's better to check two list and set logs there in setData() method.

Comment: I set log inside setData() before and after this.secaoList = secao, but setData() is called only once and don't change data while scrolling.
About sort, I'm sorting on SQLite query and then inside observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the mistake here is that you are referencing only one binding in your adapter which is getting overwritten. Every time you call `onCreateViewHolder` you are changing the `binding` reference. The reason this looks okay to start with is that the `onCreateViewHolder` calls are followed by the `onBindViewHolder` calls for items visible on the screen. However as you scroll, just `onBindViewHolder` is called in order to rebind the recycled views.

What you should be doing is using your `ViewHolder` to store the individual bindings and then obtaining a reference in `onBindViewHolder` with something like `holder.binding`.

I would recommend you have a read into the view holder pattern and how to implement it!

Comment: Thanks @HenryTwist. Undertood. What I did based on your answer: insert inside `SecaoViewHolder` class the code `val binding = itemBinding`, then at `onBindViewHolder`, changed fields call from `binding.fieldName` to `holder.binding.fieldName`, and know work correctly. Thanks again!